# Build a born-again tree from XGboost set of trees

Tags: random-forest, boosting

I am wondering whether an approach like what is described here: https://github.com/vidalt/BA-Trees for building a single tree from a Random Forest can be applied to an XGBoost model? Is there a library that already does this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the paper in question, but a skimming suggests that it isn't particularly different for gradient boosted trees or random forests.  What matters is that the tree ensemble is constant on what the paper calls *cells*, the partition of space by the tree splitting hyperplanes (fully extended, so a refinement of the partition of space into the constant-prediction regions).  Those are the same for random forests and gradient boosted trees, the only difference is that the predicted value is aggregated differently in each of those cells.

I have no idea if this is implemented anywhere; I would guess the repository you've linked could be modified very slightly to make it work.  You'd need to be able to export the xgboost model into [the specific format they use](https://github.com/vidalt/BA-Trees/blob/master/src/resources/forests/Breast-Cancer-Wisconsin/Breast-Cancer-Wisconsin.RF1.txt), and then the actual scripts.  E.g., in their [RandomForest.cpp](https://github.com/vidalt/BA-Trees/blob/master/src/born_again_dp/RandomForest.cpp), the hyperplane getting and leaf regions will be the same, but instead of `majorityClass` you'll need the predicted values in a leaf.